# Prevent shifting/movement of the items in a cdkDropList - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am facing with a problem with Drag and Drop library in Angular Material (Angular 8).

I developed the following code:

```
<div class="example-container">
    <div id="receiver-container" cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" cdkDropList #receiver="cdkDropList"
      class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[sender]" fxLayout="row"
      fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let singleReceiver of receiverSrc" cdkDrag>
        <img class="img-images" [src]="singleReceiver">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="example-container">
    <div id="sender-container" cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" cdkDropList #sender="cdkDropList"
      class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[receiver]" fxLayout="row"
      fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let singleSender of senderSrc" cdkDrag>
        <img class="img-images-send" [src]="singleSender">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

There are 2 dropping list: **receiver** and **sender**.

Inside the lists there are images and I can move an image from the sender list to the receiver list (not viceversa).

The typescript source code of the `drop` method:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    console.log('Event: ', event);
    if (event.container.id === 'receiver-container' && event.previousContainer.id !== 'receiver-container') {
      if (event.currentIndex < this.receiverSrc.length) {
        //move item
        console.log('movement allowed');
        this.receiverSrc[event.currentIndex] = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(event.item.element.nativeElement.childNodes[0].src);
        console.log(event.item.element);
        this.senderSrc[event.previousIndex] = this.imagePlaceholder;
      }
    }
  }
```

When I drag the `img` hover the `receiver cdkDropList` the items of the receiver are shifted depending on the position of the item currently dragging (that is the standard behaviour of the "Transferring items between lists" in Angular Material Drag and Drop).

What I need is to disable shifting/movement behaviour of the items inside the receiver dropList (rearrange).

I tried to disable the movement in `CSS` with `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)` or  `transform:none` but nothing is working.

Comment: Could you find a solution ? I am stuck on a similar issue of drop-list items moving out.

Answer (score 1):

```
.cdk-drag:not(.cdk-drag-preview) {
  transform: none !important;
}
```

Unfortunatly the item is still temporarelly deleted from the incoming list.

Comment: Or directly with the directive : cdkDropListSortingDisabled

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the transform property in CSS you could try using ng-deep:

```css
.your-class::ng-deep {
  transform: none !important;
}
```